# Header alligment issue on some pages?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Ia have one weird issue with my Wordpress site. i have problem with header, it show different on this [page](https://www.radiologie-aboumadi.com/blog/) and show normally on this [page](https://www.radiologie-aboumadi.com/nos-docteurs/) for ex. On bad page header image is little moved down. i checked the CSS class:

```
.full_width_photo {
            position: relative;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            min-height: 380px;
            width: 100%
        }
```

ad tryed to add `margin-top:-80px;` but just move image inside container, not entire block as i want. Can someone to give me some tip? On image is shown the issue.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Is the menu supposed to be `sticky`? Your `CSS` seems to imply that you want this version of the header to be `sticky`.

Comment: Yes menu should be sticky. If you noticed when load the page, its showing fine, but after that simply images goes down making a big white gap between header and page header featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the  tag style attribute of the page, it has "padding-top:40px". You can just remove it to fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 CSS issues:

1. There is an inline `margin-top: 98px;` on the `<body>` element that needs to be removed. That will put the banner image in the right place.
2. The class `sticky_header` needs to be removed from the `<body>` element.
3. The element `<div class="topbar vcenter transparent"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 hidden-xs hidden-sm text-center"></div></div></div></div>` needs to be removed or assigned a style of `display: none;`.